# modify field values of one file if the value of the field at the same position in a different file is "zero"

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have two files file A and File B. File A contains some values = 0 . Based on the positions of File A "zero" values File B fields are to be made empty "". Example of the output and input is shown below. I roughly understood how to do it but not sure , can someone help. Thanks.

```
File A

ABDC1

9.88E2 9.00E1 6.50E2 5.40E1 7.43E1

6.55E2 9.89E2 0.00E0 5.45E2 7.76E1

9.88E1 9.00E2 0.00E0 5.45E1 7.67E2

6.55E2 9.89E1 5.44E2 5.45E2 9.88E2

0.377E2

EFG3

9.88E2 9.00E2 0.00E0 5.54E1 7.67E2

7.55E2 9.98E2 5.44E2 4.54E2 0.00E0

5.88E2 9.60E1 0.00E0 5.40E1 4.67E2

4.55E2 0.00E0 5.45E2 4.00E0 9.88E2

6.43E2


File B


ABDC1

8.00E0 9.40E0 6.30E0 5.43E2 7.20E1

5.00E0 9.80E1 6.50E1 5.50E1 7.76E1

9.00E0 9.70E1 6.70E1 5.54E2 7.67E2

6.50E1 9.98E2 5.48E2 5.45E2 9.88E2

6.76E1

EFG3

4.88E2 9.30E1 6.80E1 5.30E1 7.60E1

6.55E2 9.80E1 5.40E1 4.50E1 7.70E1

1.88E2 6.00E0 1.00E1 5.00E0 4.60E1

5.50E1 5.40E1 5.40E1 4.50E1 9.80E1

6.65E2


Output expected:

FILE 3 (Output):


ABDC1

8.00E0 9.40E0 6.30E0 5.43E2 7.20E1

5.00E0 9.80E1 5.50E1 7.76E1

9.00E0 9.70E1 5.54E2 7.67E2

6.50E1 9.98E2 5.48E2 5.45E2 9.88E2

6.76E1

EFG3

4.88E2 9.30E1 5.30E1 7.60E1

6.55E2 9.80E1 5.40E1 4.50E1  

1.88E2 6.00E0 5.00E0 4.60E1

5.50E1 5.40E1 4.50E1 9.80E1

6.65E1
```

I am trying to do something like this: file4.txt and file3.txt are same as file A and B above

```
 #!/bin/bash

    cp file4.txt temp.txt
    touch temp2.txt 

    i=1

    while IFS=' ' read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5


    do

      if [ $f$i = "0.00E0" ]

         then

              while IFS=' ' read -r r1 r2 r3 r4 r5

                 do

                    sed 's/$r$i/""/g' temp.txt >> temp2.txt


                  done <file4.txt

       fi

    let "i=i+1"

    done <file3.txt
```

Comment: If you want people to help you then show your effort (even if not working).

Comment: I tried to do something like this: (updated above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this awk:

```
awk 'FNR==NR && NF==1{s=$1;next}
     FNR==NR{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i=="0.00E0") a[s,FNR*100+i]++; next} 
     NF==1{s=$1;print s;next}
     NF==5{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (a[s,FNR*100+i]==1) $i=""
} 1' fileA fileB | | column -t
ABDC1
8.00E0  9.40E0  6.30E0  5.43E2  7.20E1
5.00E0  9.80E1  5.50E1  7.76E1
9.00E0  9.70E1  5.54E2  7.67E2
6.50E1  9.98E2  5.48E2  5.45E2  9.88E2
EFG3
4.88E2  9.30E1  5.30E1  7.60E1
6.55E2  9.80E1  5.40E1  4.50E1
1.88E2  6.00E0  5.00E0  4.60E1
5.50E1  5.40E1  4.50E1  9.80E1
```

Comment: Thanks!, it works fine in Cygwin, however in Linux it does not seem to work.  $i=="0.00E0" is not passing through. How can i make it work in Linux?

Comment: I just found out that the reason. It was file encoding, the input files (which were output of another script)  going into this awk,  were saved in Unicode.

Comment: When the number of lines are high in paragraphs (under ABCD1/EFG3 etc.) some of the values in file A, which are to be removed because corresponding field in file B is "0.000000E0" , do not go; the value in file A remains. It is quite random, that's what it looked like in which lines the numbers are not removed. Total number of lines this script has to process is somewhere around 250,0000 (each with 10 fields) Do you have any idea why it might happen?

Comment: Not after 250,000 lines. I found that it occurs when the last line under of the paragraph contains just one field. if the last line contains 2 or more than that number of fields it works fine.  It happens in any of the paragraphs where the last line contains just one filed.

Comment: No please not in comments, data should be provided in question for **both the files** and also show expected output.

Comment: I updated the input in the question by adding an extra field at the end of the line.

Comment: Using this awk I am getting exact output as in your expected output.

Comment: My apologises, i finally found the reason: the beginning of the file A or B starts with something like   NUVOL      7 ! FLIGHT NUMBER      7    which i thought is representative of ABDC1 or EFG3, but it is not. if the first line is one word (similar to ABDC1  ||  NUVOL7!FLIGHTNUMBER7) it works fine. So the code works good. This is applicable when the last line contains one field.